# Find letter triplets except in listed words

Tags: regex, regex-negation

`([^\W\dA-Z && (I|X|L|V|\.)])\1{2}` works in http://regex101.com/r/xB5sT0/1

How to make it work except in `\b(Fuss|Mass|Bloss|Gross)` cases?

All of the listed German words can be in the middle of the word as well, or start with small letters `(fuss|mass|bloss|gross)`

I do not want to match composita words like *Fusssoldat*, because I know everything is ok with them, because *Fuss* + *soldat* makes sense.

Comment: Does [this](http://regex101.com/r/bD3gO9/2) do what you want?

Comment: Indeed it works (on the web), but as a Perl sequence can't be used in Notepad++ or EmEditor. I guess so will EditPlus. These are my main 3 editors, would not want to add the 4th one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
([^\W\dA-Z && (I|X|L|V|\.)])\1(?<!(?i)fuss|mass|bloss|gross)\1
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/v_i3hFCKpatM8kTk)

I found a solution this way:

1. your main pattern `([^\W\dA-Z && (I|X|L|V|\.)])`
2. repeated once (!) `\1` (not twice like before)
3. look behind if the current matching isn't one of the following: `(?<!(?i)fuss|mass|bloss|gross)`
4. repeat the the main pattern match once more to ensure three occurances

Comment: Wow, not only it worked it gives a visualization. That is something great to see, never seen before. I give you my thanks.

Comment: I only wonder why https://www.debuggex.com/r/CUCZMUDvnxPEzyKK/1  says "Result: Does not match starting at the black triangle slider" because 1) it does the job 2) does it perfect http://regex101.com/r/xB5sT0/3

Comment: The pattern is not supposed to match the `sss` in `Schlussscene`?

Comment: @bukart: Ah, I see. I noticed it doesn't match at regex101.com/r/xB5sT0/3, but that's because the global modifier isn't enabled.

Comment: @Rawing why yes, matching is wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the discard technique that consists of putting the discard patterns at the beginning of a regex splitted by pipes (regex OR) and use a capturing group at the end. Like the following:

```
discard patt 1 | discard this too | another discard pattern | (keep this)
```

So, for you case you could do something like this:

```
\b(?:Fuss|Mass|Bloss|Gross)|([^\W\dA-Z && (I|X|L|V|\.)])\1{2}
```

And then access to the capturing group to grab your content.

If you use `PCRE` (Perl Compatible RegEx) regex you could use `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` flags to discard a matched pattern. Like:

```
\b(?:Fuss|Mass|Bloss|Gross)(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|([^\W\dA-Z && (I|X|L|V|\.)])\1{2}
```

If you want to learn more about this trick you can take a look at this excellent thread:

[Regex Pattern to Match, Excluding when... / Except between](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23589174/regex-pattern-to-match-excluding-when-except-between)

Comment: Sure I can use '|', but the only questions was grouping. I do not use 'PCRE'. Tested '\b(?:Fuss|Mass|Bloss|Gross)|([^\W\dA-Z && (I|X|L|V|\.)])\1{2}' on http://regex101.com/r/xB5sT0/1 - did not worked, it should have ignored Fusssoldat and found only Dusssoldat, but failed. Thanks for the detailed answer.